# Changing Woocommerce product variation with jQuery after click on autonomous button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a pop-up on a product page in Woocommerce with variation pictures and separate buttons for each variation. I want to change variation after user clicks particular button.

I've tried to add with jQuery selected to certain option but it does not update variation data just updates selection input.

When I watch form in DevTools after changing variation with classic select nothing changes in the form itself.

I've also tried to change Select value with jQuery but it's not working at all:

```
jQuery('#choose-berlin').click(function() {

        jQuery('#city').val("Berlin").change();

    });
```

Select structure:

```
<select id="city" class="" name="attribute_city" data-attribute_name="attribute_city" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="">Choose option</option>
<option value="Berlin" class="attached enabled">Berlin</option>
<option value="London" class="attached enabled">London</option>
</select>
```

One of the buttons in a pop-up:

```
<a href="#" role="button" id="choose-berlin">
    Choose Berlin
</a>
```

How to trigger variation change properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery('#choose-berlin').click(function() {
        jQuery('#city').val("Berlin").trigger('change');
});
```

This assumes that you have city added as an attribute within the `.variations_form` form.

There's a lot of underlying functionality in Woocommerce with the variation fields that have action listeners on `change` and several other custom events. If you change a select field with JS, you need to make sure you trigger a change action on the select.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately nothing happens. Yes it is listed among the others variants in `data-product_variations='[{"attributes"` in `.variations_form` form and as an option in `select #city` as listed above.